# What phase need to be given for simple project that uses maven?

Tags: java, maven

I'm very new to maven and I have a single java file which depends on other jar's etc. And for that particular class I have a set of test cases that is running.

I defined the `pom.xml` file and everything seems to be working fine.

But I'm confused about the lifephase concepts. Now I'm giving only `compile` as my life phase. But that means it wont run my `test` cases? ( note that I'm following the convention of maven as it is with my folder structure )

I wish I could do both the life-phases `compile` and `test` at same time.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you specify a lifecycle phase like this

```
mvn test
```

it will run ALL lifecycle phases in order up to and including the one you specifiy. This also means that

```
mvn compile test
```

is not necessary since

```
mvn test
```

will automatically run compile as well.  For a full, ordered list of all lifecycle phases just run

```
mvn
```

and check out the help. Fyi for the default lifecycle the phases are in order:

validate, initialize, generate-sources, process-sources, generate-resources, process-resources, compile, process-classes, generate-test-sources, process-test-sources, generate-test-resources, process-test-resources, test-compile, process-test-classes, test, prepare-package, package, pre-integration-test, integration-test, post-integration-test, verify, install, deploy

Answer (score 1):

You should read the following document: [Maven Lifecycle](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html)

Anyway, if you read that, you will learn that `test` will also `compile` your project.